# Can you import sql.gz dump file in Windows cmd?

Tags: mysql, windows

Does anyone know if it is possible to import a sql.gz file into MySQL on Windows via CMD?

```
mysql -v -u root -p db_name < prod_dump_local_20171011.sql.gz
```

but i get

> ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''.

I assume because it does not know how to handle the .gz file, I can extract it but its 10gb so if there is a way to import without doing that would be good.

Comment: How was the dump file created?

Comment: Find a win32 gzip.exe, then uncompress it this way :  "C:\bin\gzip.exe -d myfile.sql.gz"

Answer (score 0):

First step! Install gzip for windows. I recommend using chocolatey to do it: (https://chocolatey.org/install)

```
choco install gzip -y
```

Now you can descompress your gz file and send it to mysql:

```
gzip -cd backup.sql.gz > mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hLOCALHOST DATABASE
```